# Introducing foreign key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - How do I specify "ON DELETE NO ACTION"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

I have 6 entities in total but my issue is with these following 3:
`Departement`, `Filier` and `Etudiant`.

The `Departement` entity contains many `Filiere` and many `Etudiant` entities, while `Filiere` and `Etudiant` are only associate with 1 `Departement` each.

This is my error message after adding migration and trying to update the database for the first time:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Etudiant_Filiere_FiliereId' on table 'Etudiant' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

This is my `Departement` entity:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Scolarité.Models
{
    public class Departement
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Libellé Obligatoire")]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "Departement")]
        public string LibelleD { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Chef Departement Obligatoire")]
        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = " Chef Departement")]
        public string ChefD { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Filiere> Filieres { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Semestre> Semestre { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Unite> Unite { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Etudiant> Etudiant { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my `Filiere` entity:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Scolarité.Models
{
    public class Filiere
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Libellé filiére Obligatoire")]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = " Libelle Filiére")]
        public string LibelleF { get; set; }

        public int DepartementId { get; set; }
        public virtual Departement Departement { get; set; }
    
        public virtual ICollection<Etudiant> Etudiants { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Unite> Unite { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Semestre> Semestre { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my `Etudiant` entity:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Scolarité.Models
{
    public class Etudiant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nom Obligatoire")]
        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Nom { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Prenom Obligatoire")]
        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Prenom { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "CIN Obligatoire")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d{8}$", ErrorMessage = "Le CIN doit comporter 8 chiffres.")]
        public string Cin { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mot de passe Obligatoire")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = " Departement")]
        public int DepartementId { get; set; }
        public virtual Departement Departement { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = " Filiére")]
        public int FiliereId { get; set; }
        public virtual Filiere Filiere { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I checked youtube videos and other posts relating to my problem on stackoverflow and tried their solutions but they didn't work for me, although I believe I'm most likely implementing them incorrectly, and that's why I'm here now.

1. I tried making the foreign keys nullable even though they shouldn't be for my case, but that didn't solve the problem
2. I tried changing the `onDelete` option to `NoAction` and to `ClientSetNull` by going to my `DbContext` and adding the following code to the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method, but it still throws the same error message as if though I didn't change a thing:

`OnModelCreating` method for my `DbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Scolarité.Models;

public class ScolaritéContext : DbContext
{
    public ScolaritéContext(DbContextOptions<ScolaritéContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Departement> Departement { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<EE> EE { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Etudiant> Etudiant { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Filiere> Filiere { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Semestre> Semestre { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Unite> Unite { get; set; } = default!;


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Departement>()
                .HasMany(d => d.Filieres)
                .WithOne(f => f.Departement)
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.DepartementId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Filiere>()
           .HasMany(f => f.Etudiants)
           .WithOne(e => e.Filiere)
           .HasForeignKey(e => e.FiliereId)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction); 

        modelBuilder.Entity<Etudiant>()
                .HasOne(e => e.Departement)
                .WithMany(d => d.Etudiant)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.DepartementId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Etudiant>()
                .HasOne(e => e.Filiere)
                .WithMany(f => f.Etudiants)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.FiliereId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);`, adding following code to modelbuilder solved my problem:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
...
    if (modelBuilder == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");

    // for the other conventions, we do a metadata model loop
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        // equivalent of modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        entityType.SetTableName(entityType.DisplayName());

        // equivalent of modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        entityType.GetForeignKeys()
            .Where(fk => !fk.IsOwnership && fk.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(fk => fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
...
}
```

Comment: Yes ! This Wroked for me !  Thank you for taking the time to help me solve this, I'm truly gratfull and  appreciative of your support.